# Why DynamoDB deletes item one-by-one would double the write throughput

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

From the offical [article](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html) it said

*"Deleting an entire table is significantly more efficient than removing items one-by-one, which essentially doubles the write throughput as you do as many delete operations as put operations"*,

Anyone can help to explain why it would be double ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because for every put you do, you have to issue a delete **if you want to delete all the items**. Those are 2 operations... If you only do put and drop the table you don't need any delete operation, so you would perform half of the writes (only puts no deletes).